# Zend Form Decorators customization

Tags: zend-form, decorator

I was implementing the zend decorators like below:

```
$formDecorators = array(
    'FormElements',
    array( 'HtmlTag', array('tag'   => 'dl', 
                            'class' => 'survey_form')),
    'Form',
);

$elementDecorators = array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag'   => 'dd', 
                           'class' => 'survey_form_dd')),
    array('Label', array('tag'   => 'dt', 
                         'class' => 'survey_form_label name')),
);
```

generating like:

```
<dl>
<dt>
<dd class="survey_form_dd">
<label style="white-space: nowrap;">
```

Now, I want to add class to `<dd>` --> `<Label>` & also want to customize my decorators as per TABLE Structure.